# Store IP address in a variable in python

Tags: python

Can an IP address be stored in a variable in python? As,

```
ip = "123.45.67.89"
```

Comment: [Yes, it can....](http://newsbusters.org/sites/default/files/thumbnail_photos/2013/June/Yes%20We%20Can.jpg?1372368823)

Comment: This could be answered by just **trying** it

Comment: @Goblin: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? You can store a dotted quad in a string, yes. What did you expect to happen here?

Comment: Was just trying to initialize in a small sample code. Thought a string would not accept a dotted format.

Comment: @Goblin Should've just tried it. Before you ask what a thing does it's a good idea to try it first.

Answer (score 3):

The Python 3.x stdlib has an [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ipaddress.html) module that provides support for IP addresses.

**Unfortunately this is not available for Python 2.x** and so you may wish to try [this backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress/), note that the backport does not provide the full range of features but may be a good place to start.

```
# Python 3.4
In [35]: import ipaddress

In [36]: ip = ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.1')

In [37]: print(ip)
192.168.0.1

In [38]: ip
Out[38]: IPv4Address('192.168.0.1')
```

Comment: Only in Python 3.3 and up though; `raw_input` seems to indicate the OP is on Python 2 instead.

Comment: Gah. Thanks @Martijn, have edited to state it's not available with Python 2.x and have added a link to a backport.